# Best way to share a common CSS and Scripts between web applications?

Tags: windows, iis-7

**Using: Dreamweaver CS6, ColdFusion 10, CFBuilder 3 (soon)**

I'm currently developing three seperate web projects but am using the same set of resources for each project:

1. Same CSS reset and initialisation styles e.g grid layouts
2. Same JQuery initialisation files

At the moment each web project has a copy of the same files in its web root. I'd like to have a place that all the sites link to get these common shared resources. I can only think of two ways to do this, both similar:

1. Decide on a 'master' site and place all the CSS and JS files in that site only.
2. Make a new site called 'shared or common' and put all the common stuff in there. but this new site still has to reside on some domain. So I still need to choose a 'master' project.

Both the above points are somewhat difficult to do because there is no 'master' site. None of the sites are linked in any way to each other.

Say I've decided on a master site then I could then link to those files using a fully qualified URL. But this means that when I am in my development environment I won't be able to see these files and use any kind of IDE introspection to see whats in the files when I make changes (e.g. like intellisense detects whats in the files and gives you hints).

Overall whats the best way to share these resources for both development and production environments?

Update: After the answers I realised I need a virtual directory in IIS and also a virtual folder in my Windows 7 local folders where my web project files are kept.

Comment: Just create a virtual directory on your web server.  Doesn't need to be any more complicated than that.

Comment: I would suggest using bower. Its a web package manages. You can make your css/js into a bower package and install it on for each site. Then if you want to change it you can change the package and update it on each site. Common libraries such as jQuery already have a maintained package that you can update from when they change. http://bower.io/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use web server virtual directories (for IIS) or alias (for Apache).

Simply create an alias/virtual directory called 'scripts' (or whatever you want) in the web root of each site (you can do this in your development environment too, if you are using IIS or Apache) and then simply use

```
<script src="/scripts/my.js" ></script>
```

Comment: if I create a virtual directory, will Dreamweaver still be able to 'see' it? Not sure if you use DW but when you open a .cfm file it automatically shows all the included CFM templates, CSS and script files so you can easily switch between them for edits.

Comment: also where would you store this virtual directory? it will have to be in some kind of Master site so that it works in both development and production?

Comment: You don't store a virtual directory, it is simply a pointer to another directory. Pick one of your sites to be the 'master' site then point the scripts virtual directory/alias at this folder. No idea if DW can see it, have not used DW in a long, long time, but I think I recall being able to do a similar type functionality in DW. That is a separate question, though.

Comment: The Virtual Directory will only exist in IIS. But I also need it to exist in my local development files which are not in IIS. Can I create a virtual folder in Windows 7?

Comment: Why not set up IIS on your local machine? Or are you referring to using them in DW? I _think_ I recall being able to do something like virtual directories in DW, but it has been way too long for me to have any confidence in that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll venture an answer.

We have shared assets across HTTP to sister sites and some unrelated sites. But the primary site collapsed and it created a single point of failure that cascaded in insane ways across our other sites (support calls were also insane until we got the primary site fixed).

Nightmare. Never again...

What I suggest is to create an Amazon AWS S3 bucket and host your assets there.

Provided you don't exceed 20,000 requests or 15GB of data per month it is free.

[There are lots of setup examples on the internet.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3)

AND if I can set this up and get it working like a charm, then you should have no problem either.

Just a consideration...Good luck.

Comment: thanks for this, its very useful to know. the amazon service would be fine for when the site is up, but I need a way to share resources at the development stage as well. So one change in the master CSS file will affect all my sites. I can only think of something like a virtual folder in Windows 7...

Answer (score -4):

We do this without sites.  Instead we use server mappings.  In the CFAdmin tool, we have mapped logical path "/" to a directory path.  That directory path has folders for js, images, css, and templates.  Then if we want to use a javascript file, it's simply:

```
<script src = "/js/theFileIWant.js">
```

Comment: CF mappings won't help here (nor will the above code work). CF mappings are only for locating CF related sources - like .cfm or .cfc files. What you need is web server virtual directories..

Comment: Your opinion is that they won't work.  My observation is that they do.

Comment: @Dan If it is working then there is another force at work making it work.  CF server mapping have nothing to to with web requests.  Also, you are not even requesting a CFM file so CF wouldn't come into play there anyways.

Comment: It is not opinion that it won't work, it is fact. CF mappings cannot be used to load client resources like JavaScript and CSS files. If it works, it means one of 2 things: 1. You have a virtual directory (or alias) in place or B. You have a folder named 'js' in your web root.

Comment: Sorry @DanBracuk: Dave and Scott are correct. CF mappings have *no* relevance to HTTP requests in general; be they for CFM files non-CFML resources such as JS/CSS assets.